# Proguard android library project with -dontobfuscate

Tags: android, proguard

I'm running Proguard on my Android library project and process passes. The problem is when I plug my .jar to concrete app and run gradle build I get:

```
> EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION: local variable type mismatch: attempt to
> set or access a value of type java.lang.Class using a local variable
> of type java.util.Map$Entry[]. This is symptomatic of .class
> transformation tools that ignore local variable information. ...at
> bytecode offset 000000ff locals[0000]:
> Lio/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap; locals[0001]: Ljava/lang/Object;
> locals[0002]: Lio/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline; locals[0003]:
> Lio/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup; locals[0004]:
> Lio/netty/channel/ChannelHandler; locals[0005]: [Ljava/util/Map$Entry;
> locals[0006]: Ljava/util/Map; ...while working on block 00ff ...while
> working on method init:(Lio/netty/channel/Channel;)V ...while
> processing init (Lio/netty/channel/Channel;)V ...while processing
> io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.class 1 error; aborting
> 
> :app:preDexHiddenRelease FAILED
```

Problems begun when I set proguard rule:

```
-dontobfuscate
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to:
https://speakerdeck.com/chalup/proguard
though getting not the same error, I realised I must set additional flag for proguard;

-optimizations !code/allocation/variable